# How does this NIO read work under the hood?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-nio

I am new to reactive programming and I am reading [Reactive Spring by Josh Long](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Reactive_Spring.html?id=k4vYzQEACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y).

In Chapter 4 he introduces a small program to show how a non-blocking file read actually works.

```
package rsb.io;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Log4j2
class Asynchronous implements Reader, CompletionHandler<Integer, ByteBuffer> {
  private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
  private int bytesRead;
  private long position;
  private AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel;
  private Consumer<Bytes> consumer;
  private Runnable finished;
  public void read(File file, Consumer<Bytes> c, Runnable finished) throws IOException
{
  this.consumer = c;
  this.finished = finished;
  Path path = file.toPath(); 
  this.fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(path,
  Collections.singleton(StandardOpenOption.READ), this.executorService); 
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(FileCopyUtils.BUFFER_SIZE);
  this.fileChannel.read(buffer, position, buffer, this); 
  while (this.bytesRead > 0) {
  this.position = this.position + this.bytesRead;
  this.fileChannel.read(buffer, this.position, buffer, this);
  }
  }
  @Override
  public void completed(Integer result, ByteBuffer buffer) {
  this.bytesRead = result; 
  if (this.bytesRead < 0) {
  this.finished.run();
  return;
  }
  buffer.flip();
  byte[] data = new byte[buffer.limit()];
  buffer.get(data);
  
  consumer.accept(Bytes.from(data, data.length));
  buffer.clear();
  this.position = this.position + this.bytesRead;
  this.fileChannel.read(buffer, this.position, buffer, this);
  }
  @Override
  public void failed(Throwable exc, ByteBuffer attachment) {
  log.error(exc);
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of questions about how this code actually is working under the hood:

1. Why do we need a separate thread pool ? (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)`)
2. Is the reading IO operation actually happening on a thread from the thread pool? If so then what is the difference between me spinning up a thread and doing the read there? If non-blocking is just using a different thread then why do I need NIO or non-blocking APIs for that?
3. If the thread that does the actual read is waiting for the data from disk then what will happen to that thread? Will it stay blocked?
4. Again if the thread is not blocked then why not just have one thread to do all the work? Why spin up multiple threads?

I know these questions must be very basic but I am yet to get a concrete answer for any of them.

Comment: Are you sure this code works? I see infinite loop there: in `while (this.bytesRead > 0)` body  `bytesRead` is never changed.

Comment: @talex I copied the code out from the book. I made no changes.

Comment: 1. Because this isn't [tag:nonblocking] I/O at all, it is *asynchronous* I/O. The two are not the same. 2. Yes. 3. None except that the mechanics of allocating the task to the thread and calling your callback are taken care of by NIO. 3. Yes. 4. Because it is blocked. 5. This code does not work. Issuing a second read while the first one is still outstanding throws an exception whose message says so. The subsequent reads need to be issued from within the completion callback. 6. If the author of your book is representing this as working code, or as non-blocking I/O, find a better book.

Comment: @user207421 Could you elaborate why "Issuing a second read while the first one is still outstanding throws an exception" ? Can't there be multiple readers to a file without concurrency problems ?

Comment: Because that's the way it works. One outstanding read at a time. See the Javadoc. There can be multiple readers but they have to be in different processes or at least via different channels. The exception isn't a 'concurrency problem', it results from misuse of the API to do something the system cannot do. Try it and see.